# Error: 'entries' key not found in the data dictionary

Tags: python, json

I tried to get data from the json response, but I got an error

in the code above I tried to get the screen_name data but when running the code an error message appears like the following:

Error: 'entries' key not found in the data dictionary.

here is my code

```
import requests, json

cookies = { '_ga': 'GA1.2.1601287389.1693612373', '_gid': 'GA1.2.2093721332.1693612373', 'guest_id': 'v1%3A169361237346882612', '_twitter_sess': 'BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCMz%252BKVOKAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlMmY4MjljNWU4NmU4ZGM3MjNmYTIxZTdiZTEwZmZlOGI6B2lkIiU2ZGVl%250AYTIxOTg3NjZiZjBhNDE1NTg3YzJhNDFmZTRiNA%253D%253D--4201dfadddbd6bbf960940efed35636fb606f60f', 'g_state': '{i_l:0}', 'kdt': 'jWQugrH1SI3e5xivVi7lRMLcxporScsEmEt8Ok8v', 'auth_token': '78e8dab911d1b309425e67168355e9f0cd864c00', 'gt': '1697759670923116755', 'ct0': '9fa6b4c5541623270805c7e5df32964c7f270c0c2fef40ead3cc8f3b7b7f2799876e63b55832d2516b845e553b89f77758ac1d76c15c5112f8c30494d3819509e59c6e1dcab0fde7bb62d6280151d882', 'guest_id_ads': 'v1%3A169361237346882612', 'guest_id_marketing': 'v1%3A169361237346882612', 'lang': 'en', 'twid': 'u%3D1697759570998013952', 'external_referer': 'padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJ12Ozwit7owX|0|8e8t2xd8A2w%3D', 'personalization_id': 'v1_vPaHB/QSsEiqaSPojDg5MA==', }

headers = { 'Host': 'twitter.com', 'x-twitter-active-user': 'yes', 'x-twitter-client-language': 'en', 'x-csrf-token': '9fa6b4c5541623270805c7e5df32964c7f270c0c2fef40ead3cc8f3b7b7f2799876e63b55832d2516b845e553b89f77758ac1d76c15c5112f8c30494d3819509e59c6e1dcab0fde7bb62d6280151d882', 'authorization': 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; ZTE Blade V10 Vita) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.67 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'x-client-transaction-id': 'fmprT5qGNMDgX+AHLO6vF5uf5+VNzhUJEIQr3Gjh166BItoMaUeqqhQ9rfZ4b+/HqRVp3X7mIcCwNUTzm49+kQKPC8EHfw', 'x-twitter-auth-type': 'OAuth2Session', 'x-client-uuid': '253d22cd-7f10-4dfa-9f46-e5c00343fb75', 'accept': '*/*', 'referer': 'https://twitter.com/nasyaelenass/followers'}

params = { 'variables': '{"userId":"1694997070736969729","count":20,"includePromotedContent":false}', 'features': '{"rweb_lists_timeline_redesign_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled":true,"verified_phone_label_enabled":true,"creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled":false,"tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled":true,"responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled":true,"graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled":true,"view_counts_everywhere_api_enabled":true,"longform_notetweets_consumption_enabled":true,"responsive_web_twitter_article_tweet_consumption_enabled":false,"tweet_awards_web_tipping_enabled":false,"freedom_of_speech_not_reach_fetch_enabled":true,"standardized_nudges_misinfo":true,"tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled":true,"longform_notetweets_rich_text_read_enabled":true,"longform_notetweets_inline_media_enabled":true,"responsive_web_media_download_video_enabled":false,"responsive_web_enhance_cards_enabled":false}', }

data = requests.get( 'https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/3yX7xr2hKjcZYnXt6cU6lQ/Followers', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, ).json()

screen_name = data['data']['user']['result']['timeline']['timeline']['instructions'][0]['entries'][0]['content']['itemContent']['user_results']['result']['screen_name']

print(screen_name)
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `screen_name = data['data']['user']['result']['timeline']['timeline']['instructions'][0]['entries'][0]['content']['itemContent']['user_results']['result']['screen_name']`, how did you decide that it should say this? Step by step?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entries` key is returned in the fourth entry in the `instructions` array. You can confirm this by printing out the result to debug:

```
print(
    json.dumps(
        data["data"]["user"]["result"]["timeline"]["timeline"]["instructions"],
        indent=4,
    )
)
```

```
% python3 test.py 
[
    {
        "type": "TimelineClearCache"
    },
    {
        "type": "TimelineTerminateTimeline",
        "direction": "Top"
    },
    {
        "type": "TimelineTerminateTimeline",
        "direction": "Bottom"
    },
    {
        "type": "TimelineAddEntries",
        "entries": [
            {
[...]
]
```

In the same vein, the `screen_name` key is also not in `result`. It's in the `legacy` key, which fetches your result:

```
screen_name = (
    data["data"]["user"]["result"]["timeline"]["timeline"]["instructions"][3][
        "entries"
    ][0]["content"]["itemContent"]["user_results"]["result"]["legacy"]["screen_name"],
)

print(screen_name)

# Returns "lindavvira"
```